# Service routing with Ingress on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

We are running several services in a Kubernetes cluster on GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine) and are having trouble configuring routing with Ingress.

Let's say that we have `auth-service` and `user-service` and would like to access them by the following urls: `http://www.example.com/auth` and `http://www.example.com/user`. All requests to these urls should be redirected to the correct services and routed internally (`http://www.example.com/user/people` -> `http://user-service/people`).

These is our configuration for the auth service:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-auth
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api-auth
        tier: backend
        track: stable
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: api-auth
          image: "<our-image>"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 9000
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 9000
            initialDelaySeconds: 180
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 9000
            initialDelaySeconds: 180
            timeoutSeconds: 5
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: auth-service
  labels:
    app: api-auth
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: api-auth
    tier: backend
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 9000
```

Internally, the service is running on Tomcat on port 9000, this part is working fine.

The problem is with our Ingress configuration:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: auth-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: <our-static-api>
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
  labels:
    app: api-auth
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /auth
        backend:
          serviceName: auth-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /auth/*
        backend:
          serviceName: auth-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /user
        backend:
          serviceName: user-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /user/*
        backend:
          serviceName: user-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Whenever I access our static api (let's call it `example.com` for now) in the following way: `http://www.example.com/auth`, I am getting 502 - Bad gateway. Running `kubectl describe ingress` says, that our services's health is `unknown`.

I am running our of ideas what might be causing this strange behavior. Could someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Are you certain the /health path is returning a 200 status code?

Comment: `kubectl get pods` indicate that they are ready

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned on Slack the services are Spring Boot apps. It's probably not related to that, but you need to make sure the ingress path matches the context of your Spring Boot app, i. e. if your ingress path is `/user`, your app context must be configured with `server.context-path=/user`. The service would then be reachable under `http://user-service/user`.

Comment: We have tried adding the context path but it did not do anything. Isn't there a way how to route the request without the need to care about the context path in the target service?

Comment: I don't think there is. We do it exactly as I described and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your health check will [reflect your readiness probes](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/master/README.md#user-content-health-checks). The health check needs to use your nodePort port because the request is coming from a Load Balancer. If your health check is targeting port 9000, the request will not get through because that port on the node is not active.

Make sure your LB health check is targeting the correct port (in the 30000 range) and that the target path will respond with 200, otherwise your health checks will continue to fail and you will continue to get 502 errors

Comment: That readiness/liveness is for the deployment, so Pods AFAIK. Querying `kubectl get pods` yields healthy result. Should there be another special liveness/readiness settings for the services?

Comment: You don't need to prepare one, but GCP will create a health check for the LB based on the readiness check.
Go to Network Services > Load balancing, you will see a L7LB created based on your ingress (default name convention is k8s-um-[NAMESPACE]-[INGRESS_NAME]--#############) . Expand that and look for  "Health check". Click on the link and make sure the "Port" field matches your Node Port

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'm not sure that Port and NodePort must match (Port exposes the service withing the cluster, NodePort for outside users - as docs say). What are the implications if they don't match? Everything seems to be working now - the problem, as Reinhard pointed out was the contextPath settings in Spring Boot and flags are green in the console.

Comment: The port and node port don't have to match within the service config. I'm referring to the L7LB health check which needs to be configured to the right port. The health check is not explicitly configured, GCP makes one when your Ingress creates the L7LB and if the port config there is off, the health check fails which leads to 502 errors.